# How to delete a plan from Microsoft Planner?

Tags: office365, microsoft-planner, microsoft-teams

From the Planner hub, in the plans dropdown menu, there is no option to delete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open the plan, click the ... menu to the right of the tab navigation and then go to "Plan settings":

[image]

From here, you will see the option to delete the plan:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking "Delete plan" alone will not remove the plan from the planner hub. There is an additional step.

First, delete the plan as normal.

- Click into the plan
- Click the three dots at the top
- Plan Settings
- Delete

At this point, your plan will still show in your list. To remove it completely:

- Click into the plan again
- Click the three dots at the top
- Plan Settings
- Edit group
- Delete group

Credit to [Alex Mynott](https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum/suggestions/13223217-delete-plans-completely).